# How can I be in good standing with the author's license of an open-source framework?

Tags: angularjs, frameworks, open-source

When I use an open source framework like Angular to create an application, and I sell this application to a client, how can I be sure that I am good with the author of the framework (Google)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing instead of directly about programming. **[See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963/1402846)** for details and the **[help]** for more.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing instead of directly about programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general open-source stuffs are usually free to use commercially. As per your question, Angular is licensed under the [MIT License](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/LICENSE).

Here is the license:

> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
>   of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
>   in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
>   furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
>
> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
>   all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
>
> THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.

There's absolutely no restriction on commercial use in there. The only requirement is that you must include the MIT copyright notice with any copies of the software. Other than that, it's a free license, and allows you to use the software for any purpose you might like, including commercial and for-profit use.

Comment: Careful, not all open-source libraries allow commercial reuse, especially not without restriction. Most promonently, many variants of the GPL license impose strong restrictions on reuse, such as having to release your application under the same license; https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/47032/can-i-use-gpl-software-in-a-commercial-application

Comment: You wrote: In general *all* open-source stuffs [...] And I am not even sure that a majority of open source code is free for commercial reuse. The rest of your answer is correct, sure, but the first sentence is highly misleading.